# Print multiline string variable without indent

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I print a multiline string variable to the console without the indent?

At the moment I tried this without success:

```
# Grid.
grid = """rnbqkbnr
          pppppppp
          ********
          ********
          ********
          PPPPPPPP
          RNBQKBNR"""

# Show grid.
print(grid)
```

The output is the following:

```
rnbqkbnr
             pppppppp
             ********
             ********
             ********
             PPPPPPPP
             RNBQKBNR
```

This is the output where I am looking for:

```
rnbqkbnr
pppppppp
********
********
********
PPPPPPPP
RNBQKBNR
```

Comment: Cross-site dupe: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/60366

Comment: This is very similar to doc strings, for which there exists a [general algorithm](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#handling-docstring-indentation) as for how to parse the identation. You can reuse the code from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print('\n'.join(grid.split()))
```

if you have inner spaces in your lines which you want to keep:

```
for line in grid.splitlines():
    print(line.strip())
```

Comment: This is a satisfactory solution for the OP's specific example, but take care: if the text grid contains internal spaces, those will get split as well. Ex. `"foo bar \n aaaaaaa \n bbbbbbb"` will put "foo" and "bar" on separate lines.

Comment: Note that this will also get rid of nested indentation which might not be desireable.

Answer (score 23):

Use [`textwrap.dedent(text)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent).

```
>>> from textwrap import dedent
>>> dedent("""\
    rnbqkbnr
    pppppppp
    ********
    ********
    ********
    PPPPPPPP
    RNBQKBNR""")
'rnbqkbnr\npppppppp\n********\n********\n********\nPPPPPPPP\nRNBQKBNR'
>>> print(_)
rnbqkbnr
pppppppp
********
********
********
PPPPPPPP
RNBQKBNR
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
# Grid.
grid = """\
rnbqkbnr
pppppppp
********
********
********
PPPPPPPP
RNBQKBNR"""

# Show grid.
print(grid)
```

Putting `\` at the end of a line removes unnecessary newline character.

Comment: Thanks, also a nice suitable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Simply don't indent inside of `"""`:

```
# Grid.
grid = """rnbqkbnr
pppppppp
********
********
********
PPPPPPPP
RNBQKBNR"""

# Show grid.
print(grid)
```

Works as expected.

Comment: Yep, this is the most straightforward solution. And if you want the "rnb..." line to align nicely with the rest of the lines in your source, you can do `grid = """\ ` and then put `rnb...` on the next line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time. But I want to avoid this solution.

Comment: Sometimes I want to indent the multi-line string because it is inside a code block that already has indent. A multi-line string without indent would make the code harder to read.

Comment: @NiclasvonCaprivi I never claimed that this was *the* solution -- but it is *a* solution. Some people don't realize that multi-line strings inside indented code blocks don't themselves need to be indented.

Answer (score 1):

```
def unindent(string):
    return ''.join(map(str.lstrip, string.splitlines(1)))

# Grid.
grid = """rnbqkbnr
          pppppppp
          ********
          ********
          ********
          PPPPPPPP
          RNBQKBNR"""

# Show grid.
print(unindent(grid))
```

Answer (score 0):

Could also try the `re` module and remove leading spaces for all lines:

```
grid = """rnbqkbnr
          pppppppp
          ********
          ********
          ********
          PPPPPPPP
          RNBQKBNR"""
​
import re
print(re.sub('^\s+', '', grid, flags=re.MULTILINE))

rnbqkbnr
pppppppp
********
********
********
PPPPPPPP
RNBQKBNR
```